# CSS3 dropdown menu overflow issues

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, overflow

Currently the last item of the menu seems to almost appear behind the white area however that is not the case. At first I thought it was a z-index issue but after some more digging I managed to figure out that it was the overflow. I have tried changing the overflow to none however it breaks the entire layout. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

http://www.hamiltonseniorcity.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
#outer > header .navigation > ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#outer > header .navigation ul > li.housing {
    line-height: 51px;
}
```

Update:

```
#outer > header .navigation > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```